# How to calculate the "Left" Property to center a Text in a DBGrid Cell?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

Continuing with the project started in:

[How to auto fit/scale DBGrid's (or other similar) columns widths according to its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292937/how-to-auto-fit-dbgrid-or-other-similar-columns-with-its-contents)

**How to calculate the "Left" Property to center a Text in a DBGrid Cell?**

When we call OnDrawColumnCell and use the Canvas to write a text in replacement of the default draw of the grid, how may we calculate the position of the text when we want to center it on the cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't. Paint the text with [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`DrawTextEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162499(v=vs.85).aspx) and specify `DT_CENTER` in the format parameter. See also [Draw text multiline in the centre of a rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007280/delphi-draw-text-multiline-in-the-centre-of-a-rect).

Or if you want or need to calculate it yourself:

```
procedure DrawCenteredText(Canvas: TCanvas; const S: String; R: TRect);
var
  Left: Integer;
begin
  Left := R.Left + (R.Right - R.Left - Canvas.TextWidth(S)) div 2;
```

Answer (score 5):

An easier way with more possibilities will be:

```
Canvas.TextRect(Rect,s,[tfCenter,tfVerticalCenter,tfSingleLine]);
```

Comment: @NGLN, @bummi, `There is no overloaded version of '%s' that can be called with these arguments (E2250)`

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I had found a reference of it being present in D2005, but apparently it isn't in D2006 yet!